# Is there anything the Matter Modeling community needs from the SE company?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

In light of this question that was asked yesterday on the Mother Meta:
[Magic wand time - what does your community need? (More questions from the Community VP)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367906/391772), is there anything we need?

Answer (score 5):

[Hierarchical tagging has already been suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367906/magic-wand-time-what-does-your-community-need-more-questions-from-the-commun#comment1227391_367983), and as you can see from my comment, I really like this idea since it would allow us to put [software-recommendations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations), [software-assistance](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-assistance), and [software-input-file-request](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-input-file-request) all under [software](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software), and [td-dft](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/td-dft) under [dft](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dft) for example.

Comment: I have to argue against this. I think it is better to use multiple tags for this. So `dft` + `td` and `software` + `assistance`. Each tag may be associated with some other tag as well and be perfectly reasonable. It requires one to search with "multi" tags, but on the other hand it can be way more powerful

Answer (score 3):

Tables should be sortable, like they are on GitHub and Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

Things that would help small sites in particular, such as lower thresholds for creating tag synonyms (it's basically impossible for anyone other than a mod to do it on a small site).

Answer (score 2):

More badges!

There's basically no more badges for me to obtain here, apart from what's not realistically obtainable in the span of the next couple years *at least*!

Answer (score 2):

Migrations of questions across the network, could be significantly improved! The asker of this question doesn't seem to even be aware that their question got migrated: [How to extract transition density cube from .fch file in Gaussian?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6506/5)

Answer (score 1):

Stricter rules against sockpuppets would benefit communities like ours.

Answer (score 0):

Better support for hyperlinking when sharing questions or answers. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ability to merge unregistered accounts with real ones in obvious cases.